# I have problem with TOTP in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, totp

I write this code in python at jupyter notebook envirment. I try to implement TOTP without build in library "pyotp". I generate QR code and scan it with google authenticator but the code which authenticator generates dose not match the code generated with my python code!!

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import struct
import time
import base64
import os
import qrcode
from IPython.display import Image

secret_key = base64.b32encode(os.urandom(10))
print(secret_key)


def generate_totp(secret, time_step=30, digits=6):
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    counter = timestamp // time_step
    counter_bytes = struct.pack('>Q', counter)
    hmac_sha1 = hmac.new(secret, counter_bytes, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    offset = hmac_sha1[-1] & 0x0F
    binary = struct.unpack('>I', hmac_sha1[offset:offset + 4])[0]
    totp = binary % 10 ** digits
    return str(totp).zfill(digits)


totp_code = generate_totp(secret_key)

otp_uri = f'otpauth://totp/MyServiceName?secret={secret_key.decode()}'
qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, box_size=10, border=5)
qr.add_data(otp_uri)
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
img.save('totp_qr.png')
Image(filename='totp_qr.png')

user_input_code =int(input("Please, enter your code: "))
is_valid = int(generate_totp(secret_key))

if is_valid == user_input_code:
    print("User's TOTP code is valid")
else:
    print("User's TOTP code is not valid")
```